# Question about using bitshift operators on int

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift

I am a beginner so dont get mad at my simple question but suppose I have an int variable
lets say a, and I do `a<<3` will that be equal to `a*2^3` = `a*8` as I read that bitshift operators multiply the variable with `2^x`.
Am I correct or I am misreading this situation??
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, unless it overflows.

Comment: Another exception is if `a` is negative, `a<<3` results in UB. (And if `a` is negative, `a>>3` results in an implementation-defined value.)

Comment: @Ian Abbott A comprehensive list of exceptions can be found in my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with some exceptions.

Consider `123410 × 103 = 123400010`. We added zeroes to the right of the decimal representation of the number by multiplying it by a power of ten.

Similarly, we can add zeroes to the right of the binary representation of the number by multiplying it by a power of two. For example, `10112 × 23 = 10110002`.

The exceptions fall into two categories.

**Exceptions due to overflow**

- If the left operand has an unsigned type, and the result is too large for that type, the most significant bits will be dropped.

  For example, in an environment with a 32-bit `unsigned int` type, `8000000116 × 21 = 1000000216`, but `0x80000001u << 1` produces the chopped result `0x0000002u`.
- If the left operand has an signed type, and the result is too large for that type, the behaviour is undefined.

  For example, in an environment with a 32-bit `int` type, the behaviour of `1 << 31` is undefined.

**Exceptions due to weird operands**

- If the value of the right operand is negative, the behaviour is undefined.

  For example, the behaviour of `1 << -1` is undefined.
- If the value of the left operand is negative, the behaviour is undefined.

  For example, the behaviour of `-1 << 1` is undefined.
- If the value of the right operand is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behaviour is undefined.

  For example, in an environment with a 32-bit `unsigned int` type, the behaviour of `1u << 32` is undefined.

---

C17, on the semantics of `<<`:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: did you mean " 1 << 32 is undefined"?

Comment: @Nick Keighley, No. The behaviour of `1u << 32` is indeed undefined because 32 is greater than or equal to the width of an `unsigned int` in the example. See the first paragraph I quoted from the C17 standard. The behaviour of `1 << 32`  is also undefined for the same reason, but it's also undefined for another reason, so it's a poorer example.

Comment: I was making the point that 1 << 31 *isn't* undefined.

Comment: @Nick Keighley, The left operand is an `int`, which is a signed type. And 1 * 2^31 = 0x8000 0000[16], which is one larger than a 32-bit `int` can hold. So the behaviour of `1 << 31` is undefined. See the last sentence of the second paragraph I quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Left shift simply means to shift the set binary values to some places to the left. for example, 3 has a binary value of 11 so doing 3<<3 means we left shift these set bits (1) to 3 places to the left. so 11 becomes 11000 which is equal to 24.

Comment: Re “simply means”: It does not simply mean that, because there are bits being shifted out and also bits being shifted in. The bits being shifted in are simple; they are zeros. But the bits being shifted out cause problems. What happens to the sign bit? What happens if other bits being shifted out are 1s? Do they vanish? The C standard does not define this. Implementations could discard the bits. They could retain the sign bit. They could signal an overflow. A problem with telling somebody something is simple is they will then be unaware of complications that could break their program.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Those cases are addressed by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! By bitshifting to the left you multiply your integer value with 2.

Visualising it, you do the following:
Let's say a is an 8-bit integer and is equal to 1.
That means that the binary code will look like: 00000001

Now if we bit shift 3 times to the left, that binary code becomes 00001000, which is 8.

Comment: There are complications, noted in my comment on the other answer, that students should be made aware of so that they know to pay attention to them in the future so their programs do not break.